# Why Oracle won't connect using an hostname inside the TNS connection string?

Tags: oracle, vbscript, odbc, adodb

I'm trying to connect from TestComplete (a test automation tool) using VBScript.

This is the code I'm using:

```
connectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my.host.machine.lan)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TEST)));User Id=myUser;Password=myPass;"

Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
connection.Open connectString
Set DB_connect = connection
```

When I run the code the error arises:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

But when I use the ip address instead of the hostname it works fine.

Also, if I use a TNSNAME, setting the TNS description with the hostname, it works.

Why the ODBC driver for Oracle does not understand the hostname?

Note:
I need to use the hostname because the ip address could change, and I need to use the "inline TNS" because it's easier to share the project without the tnsnames.ora.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the host name is reachable, when I make a ping, it is correctly resolved to the ip address

Comment: Other things that works:
TNSPING; 
SQLPLUS; 
using the tns named connection in the tnsnames.ora, in which the connection is specified with the host name